# How Do You Boost Longer Documents In lucene

Tags: solr, lucene, lucene.net, elasticsearch

I have an index of short phrases containing 1-10 sentences. The longer phrases are more relevant results, but because the term frequency is lower they score below all the 1 liners. What I would like to do is boost on the inverse of term frequency, or just give a boost to documents that are longer.

I'm using C#, NEST, and ElasticSearch, but I'm not sure how to go about this with even raw Lucene so anything would help.

### example

If I search for **"written article"** short documents like *doc 2* are consitently at the top, while the good results like *doc 1* are at the bottom.  How can I reverse this?

**Doc 2**

> cats can't **write articles**

**Doc 1**

> this is a well **written** and thought out **article**.Lorem ipsum dolor sit
>   amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque ornare sem ac arcu posuere
>   viverra. Integer egestas pharetra nunc nec cursus. Nam rhoncus sem nec
>   sem laoreet tincidunt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe add file length field and boost it?

or

Have you tried removing norms using [omitNorms=true](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml), and thus removing length normalization so shorter documents are not boosted?

Comment: I'll try omitNorms and report back. If I added filelength as a field, what would the query look like?  A dismax with 3 queries?
maybe (q=Length:[* TO 50]&qf=Length^1.0), (q=Length:[50 TO 250]&qf=Length^1.5), (q=Length:[250 TO *]&qf=Length^2.0)
 --Do you have any thoughts on the best way to structure it?

Comment: why not use bf? http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#bf_.28Boost_Functions.29

Comment: Once you've created article_length field you can use custom_score query and write a script to include length in your calculations. Use omit_norms together with custom_scoring query.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of storing the article length and then using a script to output the score, use the length to calculate a `_boost` which you can store with the document.  So eg a short document might have a boost of 1, while a long document might have a boost of 3.  That would perform better than using a script, whose output can't be cached.  See:http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/boost-field.html